# "Errors were encountered while processing: python3, python3-dbus ..." while installing packages

Tags: dpkg, python3

Friends,

when I try to install some packages on Ubuntu 20.04 (for exemple PHP) I get many errors like the following:

```
dpkg: error processing package python3-apt (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
```

and this message at the end:

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python3
 software-properties-common
 python3-requests-unixsocket
 python3-six
 unattended-upgrades
 python3-chardet
 python3-software-properties
 python3-certifi
 python3-gi
 python3-requests
 python3-idna
 python3-urllib3
 lsb-release
 python3-distro-info
 python3-pkg-resources
 python3-dbus
 python3-apt
```

The interesting thing is about it is that `python 3` seems to be already installed. When I run `python3 --version` I get `Python 3.8.5` back.

I have already tried to solve the problem running the following commands:

```
sudo apt update --fix-missing
```

(It runs without problems)

sudo apt install -f

(I returns the same error mentioned above)

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

(I returns the same error mentioned above)

I tried to check if `dpkg` shows packages which need to be reinstalled but   `sudo dpkg -l | grep ^..r` doesn't return anything.

Any idea how could I solve this problem?

Comment: You haven't mentioned your OS & release, however if you change the default python incorrectly you risk having python3 problems which will stop many Ubuntu tools from working correctly (they rely on the python being the version your system came with or upgraded to being the default). Have you tried the usual `sudo apt -f install` & normal package fix tools; if you have then providing your OS & release details; plus `python -V; python3 -V` maybe helpful (ie. to check they match the defaults for your release).